# Firefox keep crashing

Tags: 16.04, firefox

I am using Firefox 47 on my HP Compaq 6710s Laptop. The problem is after sometime the Firefox application crashes and upon restarting the app, it sometimes crashes again or crashes after sometime.

On seeing the Debug Output:

```
Add-ons: ubufox%40ubuntu.com:3.2,foxyproxy%40eric.h.jung:4.5.6,googledictionary%40toptip.ca:7.5,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:47.0,%7Bd10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d%7D:2.7.3,adbhelper%40mozilla.org:0.8.7,fxdevtools-adapters%40mozilla.org:0.3.5,loop%40mozilla.org:1.3.2,e10srollout%40mozilla.org:1.0,firefox%40getpocket.com:1.0.2
BuildID: 20160606113944
CrashTime: 1471032700
E10SCohort: unsupportedChannel
EMCheckCompatibility: true
FramePoisonBase: 7ffffffff0dea000
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1467087309
IsGarbageCollecting: 1
Notes: OpenGL: Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) 965GM  -- 2.1 Mesa 11.2.0 -- texture_from_pixmap
FP(D000-L100000-W00000000-T0000) 
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SafeMode: 0
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 386
StartupTime: 1471032319
TelemetryEnvironment: {"build":{"applicationId":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","applicationName":"Firefox","architecture":"x86-64","buildId":"20160606113944","version":"47.0","vendor":"Mozilla","platformVersion":"47.0","xpcomAbi":"x86_64-gcc3","hotfixVersion":"20160106.01"},"partner":{"distributionId":"canonical","distributionVersion":"1.0","partnerId":null,"distributor":null,"distributorChannel":null,"partnerNames":["ubuntu "]},"system":{"memoryMB":2496,"virtualMaxMB":null,"cpu":{"count":2,"cores":2,"vendor":"GenuineIntel","family":6,"model":15,"stepping":13,"l2cacheKB":2048,"l3cacheKB":2048,"speedMHz":1801,"extensions":["hasMMX","hasSSE","hasSSE2","hasSSE3","hasSSSE3"]},"os":{"name":"Linux","version":"4.4.0-31-generic","locale":"en-IN"},"hdd":{"profile":{"model":null,"revision":null},"binary":{"model":null,"revision":null},"system":{"model":null,"revision":null}},"gfx":{"D2DEnabled":null,"DWriteEnabled":null,"adapters":[{"description":"Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) 965GM ","vendorID":"Intel Open Source Technology Center","deviceID":"Mesa DRI Intel(R) 965GM ","subsysID":null,"RAM":null,"driver":null,"driverVersion":"2.1 Mesa 11.2.0","driverDate":null,"GPUActive":true}],"monitors":[],"features":{"compositor":"basic"}}},"settings":{"blocklistEnabled":true,"e10sEnabled":false,"e10sCohort":"unsupportedChannel","telemetryEnabled":false,"locale":"en-US","update":{"channel":"release","enabled":true,"autoDownload":true},"userPrefs":{"browser.cache.disk.capacity":358400,"browser.newtabpage.enhanced":true,"browser.urlbar.suggest.searches":true,"browser.urlbar.userMadeSearchSuggestionsChoice":true},"addonCompatibilityCheckEnabled":true,"isDefaultBrowser":false,"defaultSearchEngine":"google","defaultSearchEngineData":{"name":"Google","loadPath":"[distribution]/searchplugins/locale/en-US/google.xml","submissionURL":"https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8"}},"profile":{"creationDate":16750},"addons":{"activeAddons":{"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Ubuntu modifications for Firefox","name":"Ubuntu Modifications","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"3.2","scope":8,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16696,"updateDay":16696,"signedState":2,"isSystem":false},"foxyproxy@eric.h.jung":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"FoxyProxy - Premier proxy management for Firefox","name":"FoxyProxy Standard","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"4.5.6","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16859,"updateDay":16859,"signedState":2,"isSystem":false},"googledictionary@toptip.ca":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"(former Google Dictionary and Google Translate) The in-line dictionary for any word you point to or ","name":"Wiktionary and Google Translate","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"7.5","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16902,"updateDay":16904,"signedState":2,"isSystem":false},"{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Ads were yesterday!","name":"Adblock Plus","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"2.7.3","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16895,"updateDay":16919,"signedState":2,"isSystem":false},"loop@mozilla.org":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Web sharing for Firefox","name":"Firefox Hello","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"1.3.2","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16885,"updateDay":16958,"isSystem":true},"e10srollout@mozilla.org":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Staged rollout of Firefox multi-process feature.","name":"Multi-process staged rollout","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"1.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16916,"updateDay":16958,"isSystem":true},"firefox@getpocket.com":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"When you find something you want to view later, put it in Pocket.","name":"Pocket","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"1.0.2","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16916,"updateDay":16958,"isSystem":true},"adbhelper@mozilla.org":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"An addon to ease connecting to Firefox OS devices.","name":"ADB Helper","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"0.8.7","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":17000,"updateDay":17000,"signedState":1,"isSystem":false},"fxdevtools-adapters@mozilla.org":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Protocol Adapters for Firefox Developer Tools. User documentation is available on MDN: https://devel","name":"Valence","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"0.3.5","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":17000,"updateDay":17000,"signedState":1,"isSystem":false}},"theme":{"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","blocklisted":false,"description":"The default theme.","name":"Default","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"47.0","scope":4,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16729,"updateDay":16958},"activePlugins":[{"name":"Shockwave Flash","version":"11.2.202.632","description":"Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202","blocklisted":false,"disabled":false,"clicktoplay":false,"mimeTypes":["application/x-shockwave-flash","application/futuresplash"],"updateDay":17013},{"name":"Java(TM) Plug-in 11.101.2","version":"11.101.2","description":"Next Generation Java Plug-in 11.101.2 for Mozilla browsers","blocklisted":false,"disabled":false,"clicktoplay":true,"mimeTypes":["application/x-java-vm","application/x-java-applet","application/x-java-bean","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.3","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.3","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.3","application/x-java-bean;version=1.3","application/x-java-applet;version=1.3.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.3.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.5","application/x-java-bean;version=1.5","application/x-java-applet;version=1.6","application/x-java-bean;version=1.6","application/x-java-applet;version=1.7","application/x-java-bean;version=1.7","application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.8.0_101","application/x-java-bean;jpi-version=1.8.0_101","application/x-java-applet;version=1.8","application/x-java-bean;version=1.8","application/x-java-applet;deploy=11.101.2","application/x-java-applet;javafx=8.0.101","application/x-java-vm-npruntime"],"updateDay":17025}],"activeGMPlugins":{"gmp-gmpopenh264":{"version":"1.5.3","userDisabled":false,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1}},"activeExperiment":{},"persona":null}}
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
URL: https://www.seedr.cc/
UptimeTS: 380.68444
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 47.0
useragent_locale: en-US

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

**Edit:**

Updated to Version 48, still crashing. New Crash Report:

```
Add-ons: ubufox%40ubuntu.com:3.2,foxyproxy%40eric.h.jung:4.5.6,googledictionary%40toptip.ca:7.5,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:48.0,%7Bd10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d%7D:2.7.3,adbhelper%40mozilla.org:0.8.7,fxdevtools-adapters%40mozilla.org:0.3.5,loop%40mozilla.org:1.4.3,e10srollout%40mozilla.org:1.0,firefox%40getpocket.com:1.0.4
AddonsShouldHaveBlockedE10s: 1
BuildID: 20160728203720
CrashTime: 1471163705
E10SCohort: disqualified-control
EMCheckCompatibility: true
FramePoisonBase: 7ffffffff0dea000
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1471148311
Notes: OpenGL: Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) 965GM  -- 2.1 Mesa 11.2.0 -- texture_from_pixmap
FP(D000-L10000-W00000000-T0000) 
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SafeMode: 0
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 1690
StartupTime: 1471162032
TelemetryEnvironment: {"build":{"applicationId":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","applicationName":"Firefox","architecture":"x86-64","buildId":"20160728203720","version":"48.0","vendor":"Mozilla","platformVersion":"48.0","xpcomAbi":"x86_64-gcc3","hotfixVersion":"20160106.01"},"partner":{"distributionId":"canonical","distributionVersion":"1.0","partnerId":null,"distributor":null,"distributorChannel":null,"partnerNames":["ubuntu "]},"system":{"memoryMB":2496,"virtualMaxMB":null,"cpu":{"count":2,"cores":2,"vendor":"GenuineIntel","family":6,"model":15,"stepping":13,"l2cacheKB":2048,"l3cacheKB":2048,"speedMHz":1801,"extensions":["hasMMX","hasSSE","hasSSE2","hasSSE3","hasSSSE3"]},"os":{"name":"Linux","version":"4.4.0-34-generic","locale":"en-IN"},"hdd":{"profile":{"model":null,"revision":null},"binary":{"model":null,"revision":null},"system":{"model":null,"revision":null}},"gfx":{"D2DEnabled":null,"DWriteEnabled":null,"adapters":[{"description":"Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) 965GM ","vendorID":"Intel Open Source Technology Center","deviceID":"Mesa DRI Intel(R) 965GM ","subsysID":null,"RAM":null,"driver":null,"driverVersion":"2.1 Mesa 11.2.0","driverDate":null,"GPUActive":true}],"monitors":[],"features":{"compositor":"basic"}}},"settings":{"blocklistEnabled":true,"e10sEnabled":false,"e10sCohort":"disqualified-control","telemetryEnabled":false,"locale":"en-US","update":{"channel":"release","enabled":true,"autoDownload":true},"userPrefs":{"browser.cache.disk.capacity":358400,"browser.newtabpage.enhanced":true,"browser.urlbar.suggest.searches":true,"browser.urlbar.userMadeSearchSuggestionsChoice":true},"addonCompatibilityCheckEnabled":true,"isDefaultBrowser":false,"defaultSearchEngine":"google","defaultSearchEngineData":{"name":"Google","loadPath":"[distribution]/searchplugins/locale/en-US/google.xml","origin":"default","submissionURL":"https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8"}},"profile":{"creationDate":16750},"addons":{"activeAddons":{"ubufox@ubuntu.com":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Ubuntu modifications for Firefox","name":"Ubuntu Modifications","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"3.2","scope":8,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16696,"updateDay":16696,"signedState":2,"isSystem":false},"foxyproxy@eric.h.jung":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"FoxyProxy - Premier proxy management for Firefox","name":"FoxyProxy Standard","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"4.5.6","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16859,"updateDay":16859,"signedState":2,"isSystem":false},"googledictionary@toptip.ca":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"(former Google Dictionary and Google Translate) The in-line dictionary for any word you point to or ","name":"Wiktionary and Google Translate","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"7.5","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16902,"updateDay":16904,"signedState":2,"isSystem":false},"{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Ads were yesterday!","name":"Adblock Plus","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"2.7.3","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16895,"updateDay":16919,"signedState":2,"isSystem":false},"adbhelper@mozilla.org":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"An addon to ease connecting to Firefox OS devices.","name":"ADB Helper","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"0.8.7","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":17000,"updateDay":17000,"signedState":1,"isSystem":false},"fxdevtools-adapters@mozilla.org":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Protocol Adapters for Firefox Developer Tools. User documentation is available on MDN: https://devel","name":"Valence","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"0.3.5","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":17000,"updateDay":17000,"signedState":1,"isSystem":false},"loop@mozilla.org":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Web sharing for Firefox","name":"Firefox Hello","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"1.4.3","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16885,"updateDay":17010,"isSystem":true},"e10srollout@mozilla.org":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Staged rollout of Firefox multi-process feature.","name":"Multi-process staged rollout","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"1.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16916,"updateDay":17010,"isSystem":true},"firefox@getpocket.com":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"When you find something you want to view later, put it in Pocket.","name":"Pocket","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"1.0.4","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16916,"updateDay":17010,"isSystem":true}},"theme":{"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","blocklisted":false,"description":"The default theme.","name":"Default","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"48.0","scope":4,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16729,"updateDay":17010},"activePlugins":[{"name":"Shockwave Flash","version":"11.2.202.632","description":"Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202","blocklisted":false,"disabled":false,"clicktoplay":false,"mimeTypes":["application/x-shockwave-flash","application/futuresplash"],"updateDay":17013},{"name":"Java(TM) Plug-in 11.101.2","version":"11.101.2","description":"Next Generation Java Plug-in 11.101.2 for Mozilla browsers","blocklisted":false,"disabled":false,"clicktoplay":true,"mimeTypes":["application/x-java-vm","application/x-java-applet","application/x-java-bean","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.3","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.3","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.3","application/x-java-bean;version=1.3","application/x-java-applet;version=1.3.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.3.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.5","application/x-java-bean;version=1.5","application/x-java-applet;version=1.6","application/x-java-bean;version=1.6","application/x-java-applet;version=1.7","application/x-java-bean;version=1.7","application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.8.0_101","application/x-java-bean;jpi-version=1.8.0_101","application/x-java-applet;version=1.8","application/x-java-bean;version=1.8","application/x-java-applet;deploy=11.101.2","application/x-java-applet;javafx=8.0.101","application/x-java-vm-npruntime"],"updateDay":17025}],"activeGMPlugins":{"gmp-gmpopenh264":{"version":"1.5.3","userDisabled":false,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1}},"activeExperiment":{},"persona":null}}
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
URL: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=google+chrome+something+went+wrong&client=ubuntu&hs=DlD&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLrfP5vcDOAhWKv48KHUAQCEkQ_AUICigD&biw=1280&bih=705#imgrc=Z8EEbJfB9RwAcM%3A
UptimeTS: 1673.582729
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 48.0
useragent_locale: en-US

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

**Edit2:**

Tried running on safe mode, worked for a while but then this:

```
AddonsShouldHaveBlockedE10s: 1
AsyncPluginInit: 0
BuildID: 20160728203720
CrashTime: 1471164968
E10SCohort: disqualified-control
EMCheckCompatibility: true
FramePoisonBase: 7ffffffff0dea000
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1471148311
Notes: OpenGL: Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) 965GM  -- 2.1 Mesa 11.2.0 -- texture_from_pixmap
FP(D000-L10000-W00000000-T0000) 
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SafeMode: 1
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 1070
StartupTime: 1471164301
TelemetryEnvironment: {"build":{"applicationId":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","applicationName":"Firefox","architecture":"x86-64","buildId":"20160728203720","version":"48.0","vendor":"Mozilla","platformVersion":"48.0","xpcomAbi":"x86_64-gcc3","hotfixVersion":"20160106.01"},"partner":{"distributionId":null,"distributionVersion":null,"partnerId":null,"distributor":null,"distributorChannel":null,"partnerNames":[]},"system":{"memoryMB":2496,"virtualMaxMB":null,"cpu":{"count":2,"cores":2,"vendor":"GenuineIntel","family":6,"model":15,"stepping":13,"l2cacheKB":2048,"l3cacheKB":2048,"speedMHz":1801,"extensions":["hasMMX","hasSSE","hasSSE2","hasSSE3","hasSSSE3"]},"os":{"name":"Linux","version":"4.4.0-34-generic","locale":"en-IN"},"hdd":{"profile":{"model":null,"revision":null},"binary":{"model":null,"revision":null},"system":{"model":null,"revision":null}},"gfx":{"D2DEnabled":null,"DWriteEnabled":null,"adapters":[{"description":"Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) 965GM ","vendorID":"Intel Open Source Technology Center","deviceID":"Mesa DRI Intel(R) 965GM ","subsysID":null,"RAM":null,"driver":null,"driverVersion":"2.1 Mesa 11.2.0","driverDate":null,"GPUActive":true}],"monitors":[],"features":{"compositor":"basic"}}},"settings":{"blocklistEnabled":true,"e10sEnabled":false,"e10sCohort":"disqualified-control","telemetryEnabled":false,"locale":"en-US","update":{"channel":"release","enabled":true,"autoDownload":true},"userPrefs":{"browser.cache.disk.capacity":358400,"browser.newtabpage.enhanced":true,"browser.urlbar.suggest.searches":true,"browser.urlbar.userMadeSearchSuggestionsChoice":true},"addonCompatibilityCheckEnabled":true,"isDefaultBrowser":false},"profile":{"creationDate":16750},"addons":{"activeAddons":{"loop@mozilla.org":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Web sharing for Firefox","name":"Firefox Hello","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"1.4.3","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16885,"updateDay":17010,"isSystem":true},"e10srollout@mozilla.org":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"Staged rollout of Firefox multi-process feature.","name":"Multi-process staged rollout","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"1.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16916,"updateDay":17010,"isSystem":true},"firefox@getpocket.com":{"blocklisted":false,"description":"When you find something you want to view later, put it in Pocket.","name":"Pocket","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"1.0.4","scope":1,"type":"extension","foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":16916,"updateDay":17010,"isSystem":true}},"theme":{},"activePlugins":[{"name":"Shockwave Flash","version":"11.2.202.632","description":"Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202","blocklisted":false,"disabled":false,"clicktoplay":false,"mimeTypes":["application/x-shockwave-flash","application/futuresplash"],"updateDay":17013},{"name":"Java(TM) Plug-in 11.101.2","version":"11.101.2","description":"Next Generation Java Plug-in 11.101.2 for Mozilla browsers","blocklisted":false,"disabled":false,"clicktoplay":true,"mimeTypes":["application/x-java-vm","application/x-java-applet","application/x-java-bean","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.3","application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.3","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.3","application/x-java-bean;version=1.3","application/x-java-applet;version=1.3.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.3.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.1","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.1","application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.2","application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.2","application/x-java-applet;version=1.5","application/x-java-bean;version=1.5","application/x-java-applet;version=1.6","application/x-java-bean;version=1.6","application/x-java-applet;version=1.7","application/x-java-bean;version=1.7","application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.8.0_101","application/x-java-bean;jpi-version=1.8.0_101","application/x-java-applet;version=1.8","application/x-java-bean;version=1.8","application/x-java-applet;deploy=11.101.2","application/x-java-applet;javafx=8.0.101","application/x-java-vm-npruntime"],"updateDay":17025}],"activeGMPlugins":{"gmp-gmpopenh264":{"version":"1.5.3","userDisabled":false,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1}},"activeExperiment":{},"persona":null}}
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
UptimeTS: 666.7553433
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 48.0
useragent_locale: en-US

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

So how to fix this?

Comment: Try updating to version 48. It's been in the repositories since about a week back.

Comment: @mikeehatever it may or may not fox this prob, because I was facing this same error on ver 45 n 46. Will try it anyway.

Comment: Well, if you want to really fix it, debug, get the source code, and fix it. It may take some non-trivial time and effort to do it, so you might want to try updating first.

Comment: Can you try starting Firefox in safe mode? It could be a bug with one of your addons.

Comment: I don't know if it will help but try to close all firefox windows and then run firefox via terminal with the command `firefox |& tee-a firefox.txt` and see if there is any messages at firefox.txt after the crash. Also delete the folders `~/.mozilla` and `~/.cache/mozilla` (you will loose all the bookmarks, configurations and addons).

Comment: @ThanosApostolou got this, `(process:13684): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 23285
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
`

Comment: @Mohit I have no idea what this means... put it in your question and wait for someone other to answer :P